# Remove blocks of XML lines based on 1 tag, keep the rest

Tags: php, xml, replace, scripting, find

We have an XML file that looks roughly like this:

```
<JOBS>
<JOB>
<STATE>VA</STATE>
<COUNTRY>United States</COUNTRY>
<EXTRA>Package</EXTRA>
</JOB>
</JOBS>
```

We have multiple entries, half containing the EXTRA tag and half that don't. I need to create a script that searches between the   tags, determines whether or not there's an EXTRA tag, and if there isn't, delete the entire block of code. We only want to keep the ones that contain the EXTRA tag.

This sounds like it wouldn't be hard to do, but I don't know where to begin as I don't have a programming background. It would need to be in PHP preferably, does anyone have any advice or recommendations?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried `XMLReader` and `XMLWriter` classes?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php  & http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Comment: I have not, I wouldn't know where to begin with those

Comment: They are actually very easy to use, and with a simple XML schema like you showed above it shouldn't be too hard.  Give swing and if you get stuck many people on here will be more willing to help if you show you did some work, some research, and show some code.  Stack Overflow is more about fixing specific problems and providing advice from more experienced developers to those just starting out.  It's just not in the right format to be able to provide as much information as would be needed, when there are plenty of tutorials out on the web that can do a much better job then what could be posted

Comment: Can u eloborate with sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

If you can load the file in one go (as in the file isn't too large), then using SimpleXML has a quick way of doing this.  Using XPath to find jobs that don't have a `<EXTRA >` element can be done using `//JOB[not(EXTRA)]` - which just says any `<JOB>` element which does not have a `<EXTRA>` element directly under it.  This then removes any nodes that match...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("out.xml");   // Change this depending on your source of XML
$noExtra = $xml->xpath("//JOB[not(EXTRA)]");
foreach ( $noExtra as $job )   {
    unset($job[0]);
}

echo $xml->asXML();   // just to show new data
```